# jquery select dropdown items by class

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to select some dropdown items which is not has `selected` class.

I have nice example on codepen. If I add `multiple="multiple"` it works well but its like normal list. I don't want

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/airsakarya/pen/dMqmoW?editors=1010)

**HTML**

```
<select id="ddlSelect">
  <option value="1">İsmail</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Hakkı</option>
  <option value="3" selected disabled>Şen</option>
</select>

<select id="ddlSelect2" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">İsmail</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Hakkı</option>
  <option value="3" selected disabled>Şen</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ddlSelect :not(option:selected)").each(function(index, value) {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });

  $("#ddlSelect2 :not(option:selected)").each(function(index, value) {
    console.info($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that is because more than one element can be selected when dropdown is having multiple attribute set.

However for single select, only one value can be selected. As a workaround you can use has attribute selector here:

```
$("#ddlSelect :not(option[selected])").each(function(index, value) {
 console.log($(this).text());
});
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqJQXY?editors=1010)**